# Creating Mp3 file from Audio

Tags: audio-software, mp3

I have some CDs with copy protection that I would like to rip to MP3s.

I have Ableton Live Lite 10 - so used it to record the Audio from the tracks - then thought I could Export the audio as MP3 from Ableton.

It sort-of worked - but created a file with a ".mp3.als" extension which tries to open in Ableton.

So, I changed the extension to ".mp3" and tried to open it in Windows Media Player, but got "Invalid File" or similar.

It's interesting though, because the file is the right size for an mp3, and when I tried it with Wav and Flac files, they were also the kind of size you would expect them to be - but with the same result.

Any idea how I can make an mp3 that is playable normally, either using Ableton or something else?

Comment: I guess, you are recording the audio output, while playing the CD on a standard CD player. I would first try to locate a function called *export* or similar, to get rid proprietary frame or modification. The standard open source solution is [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/), which should be able to do this out of the box.

Comment: @guidot Thank you. Yes, recorded from CD, and, yes, I am using "Export to mp3". But the export function does not just export to mp3, but this ".mp3.als" type. I'm beginning to wonder if Ableton have deliberately sabotaged the "Export" function in my version, which is the free, "Lite" version - but I can't find any evidence of that on the web. I have tinkered with Audacity in the past, but I remember having problems trying to get that to produce mp3s as well - having to install an encoder, ("Lame"?) and it still not working. I will try again though on your advice.

Comment: If this is Windows, and you can play the song, you can then record it with another application via the "Stereo Mix" device.  From there you can save it in whatever format you want.  You can do the same thing in Linux, but I'm not familiar enough with the software to name specific programs.

Comment: @Duston This sounds like it might be my answer - but can't seem to get the "Stereo Mix" device at all on Windows 10. All of the advice I've seen for getting it working, seems to fall at the first fence.

Comment: It could be your sound device doesn't support it.  Have unchecked the box that says "Hide disabled devices"?

Comment: als is Live's native 'project' format. The manual should tell you how to correctly save as mp3.

Comment: I downloaded the full manual and, it turned out that it wasn't any help. By trial and error I changed an option that meant that it does at least produce an ".mp3" file now, without the ".als" suffix-suffix. However, that mp3 won't actually play in Windows Media Player for some reason - so no further forward.

Comment: You need to export it rather than save it. Go to File > Export Audio/Video. If you have the right version, there'll be an option to export mp3. If not then you should be able to export as a wav then you can use something else to convert it.

Comment: @nelgin Yes, I have been using Export all along, but there was an option that meant it produced these ".mp3.als" files - until my comment on Sep 16. It now produces a ".mp3" file - but it is unplayable, for reasons I do not understand. "Wav" seemed like a good idea - but similar result. Where Mp3 won't actually play, Wav will play, but produce silence.